# Acumatica Add Filter on Create Requisition Screen

Tags: acumatica

May I ask for your guidance here, my problem is I added a Branch Filter on the Create Requisition(RQ504000) screen, I tried to override the RQRequestProcessing Class but it just don't work. I also tried adding a WhereAnd on the Records view upon field updated but it also does not work. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you following solution:

```
public class RQRequestSelectionExt : PXCacheExtension<RQRequestSelection>
{
    #region AllocatedAmount2
    public abstract class usrBranchID : IBqlField
    {
    }

    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Branch ID")]
    [PXDefault(2)]
    [Branch]
    public int? UsrBranchID { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class RQRequestProcessExt : PXGraphExtension<RQRequestProcess>
{
    [PXFilterable(new System.Type[] { })]
    public RQRequestProcess.RQRequestProcessing Records;


    public IEnumerable records()
    {
        var currentFilter = Base.Filter.Current;
        var filterExt = currentFilter.GetExtension<RQRequestSelectionExt>();
        var newList = Base.Records.Select();
        ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

        foreach (PXResult<RQRequestLineOwned> listItme in newList)
        {
            var row = listItme.GetItem<RQRequestLineOwned>();
            if (filterExt.UsrBranchID != null)
            {                  
              if (row.BranchID == filterExt.UsrBranchID)
              {
                  result.Add(row);                  
              }                    
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(row);
            }

        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Another one, you can try to play with WhereAnd, but I for myself wasn't very successful with it.

Comment: Hi Yura, thanks it's actually working. I just added some validation when the BranchID is null it should display all the Request. Thank you so much